# Emit event dont work and active icon on current button vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I try to achieve a theme changer with vue3 and tailwind. The problem I face is with the emit event and I don't know how to show the selected current button. First the emit event problem is I setup "correctly" way, I think, see on code above. The second is I try when click the current color theme then an icon is active on the current button. If I set the code out side without be a component then works fine.

theme changer:

```html
<template>
  <div class="flex space-x-1 bg-white rounded-full px-2 py-1">
    <button
      class="rounded-full"
      v-for="(themeColor, index) in themeColors"
      :key="`theme-changer-${index}`"
      :class="[index ? 'p-3' : 'p-1']"
      :style="{ backgroundColor: colors[themeColor][500] }"
      @click="$emit('color', colors[themeColor])"
    >
      <svg v-if="!index" class="text-white w-4 h-4" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M19.916 4.626a.75.75 0 01.208 1.04l-9 13.5a.75.75 0 01-1.154.114l-6-6a.75.75 0 011.06-1.06l5.353 5.353 8.493-12.739a.75.75 0 011.04-.208z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import colors from 'tailwindcss/colors'

defineProps({
  themeColors: Array
})

defineEmits(['color'])
</script>
```

code implantation:

```html
<template>
  <ThemeChanger :theme-colors="themeColors" @colors="c => color = c" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import ThemeChanger from '@/components/ThemeChanger.vue'
import colors from 'tailwindcss/colors'

const themeColors = [
  'indigo',
  'emerald',
  'blue',
  'yellow',
  'orange',
  'red',
]

const color = ref(colors[themeColors[0]])
</script>
```

Comment: Please create a stackblitz or code sandbox.

Comment: I add codesandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are emitting an event called `color` at `@click="$emit('color', colors[themeColor])"`,

but you are listening to an event called `colors` at `<ThemeChanger :theme-colors="themeColors" @colors="c => color = c" />`

I think changing the event names so that these two match would be sufficient to get your code working.

In regards to getting the check mark change with the current theme, there are multiple ways you could go about it. I think the best way (easy, but scalabole) to do this would be to have another prop called something like `currentThemeColor` on your `ThemeChanger`.

Then, in your `v-for` loop, you could do something like:

```html
<button
  class="rounded-full"
  v-for="(themeColor, index) in themeColors"
  :key="`theme-changer-${index}`"
  :class="[index ? 'p-3' : 'p-1']"
  :style="{ backgroundColor: colors[themeColor][500] }"
  @click="$emit('color', colors[themeColor])"
>
<svg v-if="currentThemeColor === themeColor" ... >
</div>
```

This way, your `ThemeChanger` would be re-rendered every time the prop changes and react accordingly. Using `ref`s would be another way, but I think later on, you will want to eventually move the theme logic out of the parent component and move it to some kind of global provider, and using props would work with that kind of setup as well with minimal changes.

Comment: Oooh my god that was the problem. You save me. Thanks by the way.

Comment: The other "problem" how to make the check icon change on true/false when color is active?

Comment: @Dasd edited my answer to answer that question as well!